# How to create custom collection subscript that handles RawRepresentable value

Tags: ios, swift, generics, collections

I am creating a custom collection that wrappers Dictionary.
This collection should identify when it gets an enum that has a raw value of type: string/int and if so then it will extract the "rawValue" from it automatically.

One of my subscripts should handle the case the key of the subscript is of type `String`, and the value is `Enum` case
for example:

```
dict["userEvent"] = Event.tap
```

I tried :

```
subscript<Index: ExpressibleByStringLiteral>(index: Index) -> Value? where Value == RawRepresentable {
    get {
        return self.elements[index as! Key]
    }
    set {
        self.elements[index as! Key] = newValue?.rawValue
    }
}
```

But I'm having the following errors:

> Protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

and

> Member 'rawValue' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'RawRepresentable'; use a generic constraint instead

How can I implement this subscript that will automatically unwrap the enum case while setting new value?

Comment: What is the `index as! Key` part? Shouldn't `Key` always be a `String`? Could you please add requirements of your collection as it might be easier to advise you.

Comment: @MaticOblak I didn't have to use this `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, I deleted it.
The requirements are to cover all the possible combination of assigning and accessing this custom collection with an enum. For example (key is enum: value is String), (key is enum, value is enum). btw now I can see that the problem is when both the key and value are an enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RawRepresentable` has generic constraints. What you can do is add the "Return" type as another parameter in your generic constraints for your subscript. Like this:

`subscript<Index: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Return: RawRepresentable>(index: Index) -> Return?`

But I am not confident this kind of configuration will work. Is this dictionary wrapper is a distinct subclass of `Dictionary` or an extension of `Dictionary`?

Comment: Thanks! In case both the key and value are an enum, how can I implement that?

Comment: `RawRepresentable`'s `RawValue` associated type should match your enum's `RawValue` type. Then you can add to the function definition above this: `when Return.RawValue == <your enum type's raw value>`

Comment: But this will only work on one particular enum raw value type. There are easier ways to store dictionary of enums by actually storing the said enum outright.